# plotting white stuff over a plot in python

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, colors

I've got some trouble with plotting white spans over a plot.
I've created and plotted a given function `y(x)` and defined some "forbidden" regions, corresponding to some `x` intervals. Now I want to visually "erase" these forbidden portions by overplotting some white bars, by using the `matplotlib axvspan`.
However, if I try to plot a white span, the underlying plot is still visible, although I use different alphas and although I put the `axvspan` command after the `y(x)` plot. Is there a way to make the white span cover the underlying plot? Thank you in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,8))
plt.step(np.arange(0,10,0.1), np.arange(0,10,0.1))
plt.axvspan(2,5, color='white')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `plt.axvspan(..., zorder=3)` to change the order in which the vspan is drawn. Lines have zorder 2 by default. Or you could change the zorder of the line to `-1` so you can still add other stuff to the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Using axvspan will draw a portion "behind" your plot , as you can see here ([1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dLWh.png) when i replaced white with red :

```
[import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,8))
plt.step(np.arange(0,10,0.1), np.arange(0,10,0.1))
plt.axvspan(2,5, color='red')
plt.show()][1]
```

You need to delete manually those portions for the array